# How to obtain Cursor via ContentResolver on ANY device?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

So far, we have solved `Cursor == null` when retrieved via `ContentResolver` by using separate logic for SDKs <11, 11-18, >=19. Something like

```
public static Cursor getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public static Cursor getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    return cursor;
}

public static Cursor getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

However, on Galaxy S5, when we save an image to its own directory in the internal public memory (not private `data/data`), we get `cursor==null`. On other devices, we DON't get null cursor.

The flow of the app is like this:

1. Take image with Camera
2. Save it into file in its own directory (public directory in internal memory)
3. Access file via `ContentResolver` and return `Cursor`

Steps 1 and 2 are properly done. Verified! I can see the image I take via Camera inside the specified directory.

I also checked if the `Bitmap` is accessible via

```
    InputStream input;
    Bitmap bmp;
    try {
        input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("tafg", "error");
    }
```

and I never get an exception.

However, in spite of all this, `Cursor` remains null on some devices. Anyone can guess why and what is the ultimate way never to get null cursor?

PS. is there any 3rd party library that handles this part properly?

PPS. We are using Retrofit to get up to 10 images saved via Camera and upload to the remote server. Using and working with `Bitmap` is not possible in this case as we get OOM on the 5th or 6th image. So Retrofit logic must use `ContentResolver` to get hold of the image(s) that need(s) to be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far, we have solved Cursor == null when retrieved via ContentResolver by using separate logic for SDKs <11, 11-18, >=19.

I strongly recommend that you delete all that code and [use a `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

> The flow of the app is like this:

Your step #3 is pointless. You know where the file is, because you put it there in step #2. And, by getting rid of step #3, you can also get rid of all of the bogus "real path" code.

> Anyone can guess why

Perhaps `MediaStore` does not know about the image, because it has not been indexed yet. See `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method.

Also note that you are not actually setting `cursor` to a value in `getRealPathFromURI_API19()`. I would expect that code to not compile, so I am assuming that it is a copy/paste problem in your question.

> what is the ultimate way never to get null cursor?

Stop querying for it in the first place.

Comment: Yes, paste issue. Fixed!

Comment: I have not said that we are using Retrofit to query the file so we can upload it to the remote server. There are up to 10 files which are being uploaded to the server at the same time. And when I click "upload images via Retrofit", the app breaks on `cursor==null`. Does this extra info on Retrofit change anything in your response?

Comment: @sandalone: Not really. In Step #2, you have a filesystem path to the image that you wrote out to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) ("Save it into file in its own directory"). Use that filesystem path with Retrofit. At best, Step #3 is a roundabout, slow, unreliable way of getting that exact same filesystem path, and I do not see how that helps you or the user.

Comment: Dropped querying Cursor, implemented your advise and fixed the issue! Thanks a million. PS. you've got a new subscriber ;)

Comment: @sandalone: "Dropped querying Cursor, implemented your advise and fixed the issue!" -- as a side benefit, it also will run a bit faster, though unless you're doing a bunch of these in succession, that probably will not be noticeable. "PS. you've got a new subscriber ;)" -- many thanks!